# How to detect a string inside an combination of characters in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I am on a problem. I have a string that look like this `@[name1](2) some Text... @[name2](3) some Text....`
I want to rearrange this string like this `name1 some Text... name2 some Text....` How can I do this. The above pattern is from **react-mentions** output. Basically, the names and the numbers next to them inside the parenthesis () can be changed but the pattern will be the same.. How can I remove that special characters and display the names and text correctly.. Please help.

Comment: Check their documentation if there is any way to get plain text without the mention syntax.

Comment: I couldn't find one for this..@adiga But my problem is solved The below comments saved my day..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a RegExp in order to replace the superfluous characters:

```js
const input = '@[name1](2) some Text... @[name2](3) some Text';

const regex = /@\[(\w*)\]\(\d+\)/g;

const output = input.replace(regex, '$1');

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Can you help me again? Can you please tell how can i retrieve only the strings inside that combination ? say i want name and the digit from @[name1](1) ..can you help me with this ?

Comment: add a capturing group (parenthesis) around the number (d+), then add $2 in the replace string wherever you want it to appear

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript's String#replace method to achieve this.

```js
let string = "@[name1](2) some Text... @[name2](3) some Text...."
let modifiedString = string.replace(/@\[(\w+)\]\(\d+\)/g,"$1")

console.log(modifiedString)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string.replace` with regular expression.

```
let str = "@[name1](2) some Text... @[name2](3) some Text...";

let result = str.replace(/@\[(\w+)\]\(\d\)/g, (m,i) => i);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks...This method is working..Once again Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
str=@[name1](2) some Text... @[name2](3) some Text....
```

looke like you want to get rid of @,[,],(and)
so what you can do is

```
   str= str.replace("@", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "");
```

I would also like to add that this is a easy but a naive solution, a better one might be possible

Comment: This will replace all instances of `@{}()` with nothing.

Comment: I dont think this will be of use..This will replace all of the mentioned characters... I just wanted to remove the characters if a special combination is found..Anyway the above comments has the solution

Comment: that is why I aslo added, that this is a naive solution

Answer (score 0):

Created a regex https://regex101.com/r/aqXegs/1/ which is basially `/@\[(\w+)\]\([0-9]+\) (\w+)/gm`.

It can be used in javascript like this `str.replace(/@\[(\w+)\]\([0-9]+\) (\w+)/gm, '$1 $2')`.

It is explained if you follow the link and the pattern is most applicable for particularly your case.